# Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 5 Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'LEFT'. Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 6 Incorrect syntax near 'b'

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

```
USE [pfebd]
SELECT *
FROM TBCSBONNV a
WHERE TBCSJRNE<=20210422 AND TBCSECHE >=20210422 AND TBCSDBSC<=20210422 
LEFT JOIN 
(SELECT DISTINCT CPGCTGS ,CPGCPT,CPTENUM FROM CPTAXNV )b
ON a.TBCSAGCC=b.CPGCTGS AND a.TBCSNUCC=b.CPTENUM;
```

Comment: [Bad Habits to Kick : Using table aliases like (a, b, c) or (t1, t2, t3)](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-table-aliases-like-a-b-c-or-t1-t2-t3)

Comment: Please read asking part of this link stackoverflow.com/help for give best feedback in site. your title is not good and your question not enough quality for asking.... please read about how to ask good question. wish you for the best

Answer (score 0):

`JOIN` is an *operator* in the `FROM` clause.  The `WHERE` clause follows the `FROM` clause.  So you seem to want:

```
SELECT c.*, a.*
FROM TBCSBONNV c LEFT JOIN
     (SELECT DISTINCT CPGCTGS, CPGCP, CPTENUM
      FROM CPTAXNV a
     ) a
     ON c.TBCSAGCC = a.CPGCTGS AND c.TBCSNUCC = a.CPTENUM;
WHERE c.TBCSJRNE <= 20210422 AND
      c.TBCSECHE >= 20210422 AND
      c.TBCSDBSC <= 20210422 ;
```

I replaced the table aliases with aliases that seem related to the table names TB**C**SBONNV and CPT**A**XNV.